# ASP.Net MVC File Upload Question

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When I want to try the file upload in ASP.Net MVC,I am receive the following error.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current 
web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error 
and     where    it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference 
not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 
Line 21:         public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
Line 22:         {
Line 23:            if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
Line 24:            {
Line 25:              string filePath =  Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath
("../../Tarifler/Videolar/"),
Source File: D:\yemekizle\yemekizle\Controllers\FileUploadController.cs  Line: 23
```

Here is my code line.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %> 

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">     
    FileUpload
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">  
    <h2>FileUpload</h2>        
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "FileUpload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { %>        
        <input name="uploadFile" type="file" />      
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Controller:

```
[HandleError]
public class FileUploadController : Controller
{    
    public ActionResult FileUpload()    
    { 
         return View();    
    }   

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]    
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)    
    {  
        if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)      
        {
            string filePath = Path.Combine(
                HttpContext.Server.MapPath("../Uploads"), 
                Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName)
            );          
            uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);    
        }      
        return View();    
    }
}
```

Where I wrong?

Thanks,

---

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
        if (uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {

          string filePath = 
     Path.Combine(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/resim"),      Path.GetFileName
      (uploadFile.FileName));
            uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);

        }
```

Comment: Only that you read the [markdown editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) section (or click the little `?` at top right of the edit box.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that the user has selected a file by checking if `uploadFile` is not null before processing it:

```
[HttpPost]    
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)    
{  
    if (uploadFile != null && uploadFile.ContentLength > 0)      
    {
        string filePath = Path.Combine(
            Server.MapPath("~/Uploads"), 
            Path.GetFileName(uploadFile.FileName)
        );          
        uploadFile.SaveAs(filePath);    
    }     
    return View();   
}
```

Also ensure you have read the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx).

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov- I can't  install a file that is .flv extension ,but I can install a file that is .jpeg extension.

Comment: @Arbelac, what do you mean by *installing a .flv extension file*?

Comment: @ Darin Dimitrov - So, I can't upload a .flv extension file.if I change as .jpeg extension of the the same file,it's working.

Comment: @Arbelac, what does *can't* mean? Error message? Something else?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov  -  Here is my error message. http://ressim.net/s/upload/82db7d36.jpg  http://ressim.net/s/upload/9bafcde2.jpg

Comment: @Arbelac, is the `uploadFile` variable assigned inside the controller action?

Answer (score 1):

I don't take the file as an Action parameter, I usually just pull it from the request. You're sending the file via a html form post, I presume?

```
public ActionResult FileUpload()
{

    foreach(var file in Request.Files)
    {
         //do something

    } 

    return
}
```